# org.w3c.dom.DOMException: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: Web Service error. Soap Exception

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl2java, domexception, soapexception

By using wsdl2java, I executed methods from a WSDL. These methods include only Remote Exceptions. When I run the program, it gives the error written on the tittle. However I am expecting a Soap Exception because when I made a request over the Soap UI, I could easily see the soap exception in the xml format. Code snipped is like that:

```
try
{
   enrollResponse = server_service.enroll(enrollParameters);
}
catch (RemoteException e)
{
   logger.fatal(e.getMessage);
}
```

---

```
Error: org.w3c.dom.DOMException: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it.
```

---

I think the problem is that the program respects a determined xml format, but the soap exception is in the different format. Therefore it gives the error. However under the remoteexception I cannot reach the xml format of soap exception.

How can I reach that exception?

Answer (score 0):

Please check version of Axis Jar.

This issue had been patched for Axis 1.3 but not for Axis 1.4.

Please refer this link

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS-2705

Comment: I have already had the same jar with the ones which are suggested the link that you gave
http://www.lacike.sk/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/axis_1.4_fix.zip It is not working.